# Display warnings and clock alarm

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

im trying to make an App that the base function is to give alerts by setting up the hour, day or week in wish the alerts will be given. an example of what i want is something like a "pill reminder".

If someone could give me a insight on how to start, since im a bit new to IOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use local notifications.

The best place to start is here:

Local and Push Notification Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Have fun !